# `nginx` reverse proxy issue in `docker`

Tags: nginx-njs

Map the `80` port of `nginx` using the port running `nginx`, `docker 11111`
`nginx` is configured as follows

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
      listen 80;
      location /goto/ {
        proxy_pass   https://www.kugou.com/;

      }
    }

}
```

For example host Ip: 114.188.16.20

Visit: 114.188.16.20:11111/goto
The expectation is to proxy to `https://www.kugou.com/`, but every visit to `114.188.16.20:11111/goto` will always be directed to `114.188.16.20/goto`, which becomes the default `80`,
how to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

`/goto/` does not match `/goto`.

Use `location /goto` .